# Logstash drop lines in file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am wondering if it is possible for logstash to ignore first 2 lines of a file? I have looked in many places and the only solution seems to be using an if to check if the line is certain text, and if so drop .. but this seems extremely inefficient as I know for a fact I only need to drop first 2 lines and dont need to "if..then" check millions or even thousands of lines that follow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, not with the existing versions.  The logstash file input only has an option for `start_postition => beginning`.

If you feel strongly about it, you could always fork the [file input](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file), update it with a `start_position => skip_lines`, add another parameter to specify how many lines, and then submit a pull request back to Elastic and it might get implemented.